# Sqoop Export Failure handling

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

I am trying to export large dataset into RDBMS table. After sometimes it is getting failed. How to deal with records which is already processed to the RDBMS. I don't want to do full load again , I want to load only remaining records. Is there any way to do this in sqoop

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do incremental load the Sqoop ( using some incremental id or date ).

But here we find issue with updates or data deletion . As it is not possible to track the changes.

We have Sqoop Merge that solves the problem but it is costly and do not have a way to track deleted record form source.